# Total Sum with multiple where clause LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sql query that works perfectly fine in SQL Server. which is

```
SELECT sum(CONVERT(float,[amount])) 
FROM [transaction] 
where [response_code] = '100' and merchant_id = '14
```

while converting it into linq, this was my resultant query and the exception I was receiving. what am I doing wrong?

LINQ =

```
float count = dbContext.transactions.Where(trx => trx.response_code.Equals("100"))
                            .Where(trx=>trx.merchant_id.Equals(mid))
                            .Sum(i => float.Parse(i.amount));
```

Error =

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'Table(transaction).Where(trx => trx.response_code.Equals("100")).Where(trx => trx.merchant_id.Equals(Convert(Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]))))).Sum(i => Parse(i.amount))' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Generator.Generate(SqlNode node, LocalBuilder locInstance)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Generator.GenerateBody(ILGenerator generator, SqlExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.CompileDynamicMethod(Generator gen, SqlExpression expression, Type elementType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile(SqlExpression expression, Type elementType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory(SqlNode node, Type elemType)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at WCF_SOAP_REST_Service.Service.totalAcceptedTransactionCount(Nullable`1 mid) in c:\Users\Monet\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WCF_SOAP_REST_Service\Service.svc.cs:line 845}
```

Comment: Try using `float a;            float.TryParse("value", out a);`

Comment: Have you tried using == instead of the .Equal function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Linq To Entities doesn't recognize the method float.Parse() and can not translate it into a valid store statement.

You have to enumerate first the Where result with the methods Select(), AsEnumerable(), ToList()...

Here you have the methods that Linq to Entities can translate into a valid Sql statement:

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738681(v=vs.100).aspx)

This should work:

```
dbContext.transactions.Where(trx => trx.response_code.Equals("100"))
    .Where(trx=>trx.merchant_id.Equals(mid))
    .ToList() // Or AsEnumerable(), or Select()...
    .Sum(i => float.Parse(i.amount));
```

Comment: `Select` doesnt enumerate a LINQ to Entities statement. `Count` will though